# Laravel null POST data in controller

Tags: laravel, controller, null

A few days ago I started to learn laravel on laracasts and I have a small problem.

When I submit a form data using post method and want to access this data in my controller, I have an empty value.

Form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/costs')}}">

{{ csrf_field() }}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cost-title">Cost title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cost-title" name="title" placeholder="Enter cost title">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cost-price">Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cost-price" name="price" placeholder="Enter price">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Cost;

class CostsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $costs = Cost::all();

        return view('costs.index', compact('costs'));

    }

    public function show(Cost $cost){

        return view('costs.show', compact('cost'));

    }

    public function create(Cost $cost){

        return view('costs.create');

    }

    public function store(){
        dd(request()->all);
    }
}
```

In my routes I'm triggering @store  using post method:

```
Route::get('/costs', 'CostsController@index');
Route::get('/cost/{cost}', 'CostsController@show');
Route::get('/costs/create', 'CostsController@create');

Route::post('/costs', 'CostsController@store');
```

And when I try to dump and die the requests:

```
public function store(){
        dd(request()->all);
    }
```

I have a null value. Can you please explain me why I can't see any data here?

Comment: Try this `public function store(Request $request){
        dd($request->all());
    }`

Comment: @Maraboc, I have tried but I have an error like this: "Class App\Http\Controllers\Request does not exist"

Comment: Add this `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` on top of your controller ;)

Comment: The error is gone but I still have a null there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your store method and pass a Request parameter like this:

```
 public function store (Request $request)
{
 $input = $request->all();
 dd($input);
}
```

Update:

```
The Illuminate\Http\Request
```

instance provides a variety of methods for examining the HTTP request for your application and extends the

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
```

If your controller method is also expecting input from a route parameter you should list your route parameters after your other dependencies. For example, if your route is defined like so:

```
Route::put('user/{id}', 'UserController@update');
```

You may still type-hint the Illuminate\Http\Request and access your route parameter id by defining your controller method as follows:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}
```

So, in simple words for getting form parameters you have to pass a variable ($request) to your controller so that it can be accessible (lets just say that laravel store these form parameters in the $request variable, so you can easily pass it to controller or not).
Hope it will clear up things :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now! But I don't understand what's the difference? Can you please explain why storing a request parameter in a separate variable and than dumping it works but my previous method does not?

Comment: Answer Updated :)

Comment: Error: Function name must be a string